# Tortoise SVN SSL error on checkout in Windows 8

Tags: svn, windows-8

I want to do a simple SVN checkout in TortoiseSVN of a secured repository in Windows 8. In the browser I AM ABLE to view the repository (by first adding an .afx certificate). 
However when i do a checkout with TortoiseSVN it freezes. When i use the RapidSVN client it gives the message:

> Error: Error while performing action: Unable to connect to a
>   repository at URL 'https://...' OPTIONS of 'https://...': SSL
>   handshake failed, client certificate was requested: SSL error: sslv3
>   alert handshake failure

To solve the problem I have tried:

- Putting the .afx file in \AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.ssl.server
- Setting TortoisePlink.exe as ssh tool
- Turning off my firewall and anti-virus

Still TortoiseSVN can't seem to find the right client certificate. So my question is this: How can i make sure TortoiseSVN is able to find my client certificate (in .afx format?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by changing your subversion configuration file?

`[subversion.example.com]
ssl-client-cert-file = /path/to/my/cert.afx
ssl-client-cert-password = somepassword`

The configuration file is usually located at:
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\config`